# running codes for categories in column

Tags: r

i have one code (fun_r1.R) which i used to run again and again for number of regions in region column.

now i am thinking like creating a list of region and then run the code one by one for all regions in "region"

also i want to create a folder for regions and then save the files in the same folder

```
    path <- getwd() 
    region<- c("CA","US","UK") # code should run for the variables here one by one
    for (i in region) {  
      folder <- paste0(path)  # here i want a new folder for CA and save the output here
    
    render (codes.r)
    save.output(path)
    }
```

what should i do for the required proble here , above is just a temporary code that i was trying to create

Comment: Can you please explain what you are asking for and where your problem is? What is wrong with the code you posted? Are you looking for the `unique()` function?